# Grease pencil and Unity

Tags: unity, grease-pencil

I have made a face animation using Grease pencil on my 3D model and I exported the model as FBX to Unity. In Unity, I can't see the face. It's just blank on the 3D model. What happen to the face animation I have drawn?

I also tried converting the GP into mesh but when I tried converting it, it gave me this notice "Current GP strokes have no valid timing data, most timing options will be hidden!"

Answer (score 1):

Short version: Render it out and make a Sprite Animation.

Long version:
Click on the Faces, where you draw the with your animation, of your Object.
Say "Object by selected". Now you have a extra Object.
Take the Camera and fix it to your Animation.
Render the whole GreasePencil Animation out. Just the GreasePencil. Use the Transparent Shader.
Create a Sprite Image, based on your rendered images.
Import your everything in Unity.

Give your Mesh the normal Materials and the FaceObject is a Sprite Image.

I learned it here.
https://www.udemy.com/course/blender-28-game-character-creation/learn/lecture/14405776#notes

I hope that helped:)